# How to use code-completion and hidden-code delimiters in Swift Playgrounds?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I’m trying to make a “learner’s” sort of Playground in Swift but every time I try to use the `code-completion` or `hidden-code` delimiters, it simply doesn’t work.

For `hidden-code`, the problem is that the code inside the start and end delimiters just vanishes upon reopening the Playground. No functions inside of that “hidden” code are there either.

For `code-completion`: reopening the Playground causes all changes to the completions in the shortcut bar at the bottom to revert back.

I have been following Apple’s documentation and nothing works, and nor have I found something else on Stack Overflow. How do I use these delimiters properly?